# Change the number of bones in Limit Weights, in 2.7+

Tags: bones, weight-painting

I'm trying to limit the number of bone-weights per vertex to 2 or 3, and there is an operator in Blender in the weight-paint mode (Tool pane) called "Limit Total". But there is no way to change the default number of 4 weights per vertex in the UI... that I can find at least. Is this a bug or omission in 2.7 or am I just UI-blind?

[How to restrict vertex weights to no more than N number of Bones?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14250/how-to-restrict-vertex-weights-to-no-more-than-n-number-of-bones)

I can do it through the python console as the underlying operator has the arg "Limit=4" as default and can be changed, but it is somewhat inconvenient..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in the UI (you need UI glasses ) in the operator properties panel:

[image]

Comment: Aha, it was that + sign in the bottom that I had to click.. I didn't know there was a hidden options panel there as well (there already is an options panel if clicking the Options vertical tab to the left :)

Comment: Seems there is a "bug" in that the panel option for Limit Total is only folded out once you already click on it, and then it has already run the limiting, which is OK if you're going to reduce the value, but would of course destroy your weights if you're in fact going to increase the value. Just noting.. :)